# Does the feat Magical Training grant a spell list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats

The benefit of the feat **Magical Training** says

> You can cast three 0-level arcane spells per day as either a sorcerer or wizard (your choice, so long as you have a score of at least 10 in the ability that controls the spellcasting for that class). You must make this decision when you first take the feat. Thereafter, you... are treated as a sorcerer or wizard of your arcane spellcaster level (minimum 1st) for the purpose of determining level-based variables of the spells you cast.
>
> If you choose to cast spells as a sorcerer [y]ou know two 0-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer/wizard list.
>
> If you choose to cast spells as a wizard, [y]ou have a spellbook with three 0-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer/wizard list. You prepare your spells exactly as a wizard does. (*Player’s Guide to Faerûn* 41)

Does a creature that takes this feat *either* gain the Sor/Wiz spell list *or* gain a spell list limited to those spells he knows *or* something else? Further, can a creature that picks to cast like a wizard prepare and cast additional 0-level sorcerer/wizard spells that the creature adds to that spellbook *or* is such a creature (if he picks no other options for wizard-like spellcasting) stuck with a 100-page book containing 3 pages of spells and 97 pages of doodles of him in wizard hat or whatever?

(Gaining the Sor/Wiz spell list—which, for example, enables the use of Sor/Wiz wands—by taking a lone feat can be a fairly big deal at low levels when making a DC 20 Use Magic Device skill check is still a challenge.)

Comment: Could you cite your specific source for needs to be on the caster's spell list? It sounds like you're mixing together restrictions on what you can learn and what you can cast.

Comment: @Fectin I adjusted the question. The rules for spell lists are spread out and vague enough that an answer may address that specifically instead.

Answer (score 5):

**I'd say that the feat grants a *Magical Training* spell list, not a Sor/Wiz spell list.**

When you take the feat, you get to pick 2-3 spells from the Sor/Wiz spell list, and *those spells* make up your spell list. You need to be an actual Sor/Wiz to gain their spell list.

Likewise, you're only considered a Sor/Wiz *with regard to those selected spells*, and for nothing else. So I'd say that you don't get to use items that require Sor/Wiz as the classes, but you still pass as an Arcane Spellcaster because those selected spells are *arcane*.

This is why the feat can pass the Dweomerkeeper's requirement (arcane spellcasting), but not exactly for the wands that you mentioned.

Comment: Presumably, you could still freely use wands of the three spells you picked though

Comment: @fectin : Yes, I think so, too. ^_^